# type hint for input parameter which will be modified

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am trying to use type hints in my python code to make it more readable and better documented and I was wondering if there is a way to specify whether the input mutable parameter will be modified the function. So, if I have a function like:

```
from typing import Dict

def something(d: Dict)
    d[1] = 'one'
```

I was wondering if I can make this explicit in the parameter signature that i will be modified by the called function.

Comment: _must_ you modify the dict, instead of creating a new one, making the change to the new one, and returning that?

Comment: Well, I do not have to but I do not perhaps want to make a copy. Anyway, the best programming practice aside, I was wondering if there is still a type hint way to document thiis.

Comment: A docstring, probably, rather than a specific type hint. After all, even in statically typed languages like Java, there's no easy way to differentiate whether a method is mutative or not by just its header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any that are offered by `typing`. But I believe you could make your own. Something like this:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')


class MutableObject(typing.Generic[T]): 
    """Object that will be mutated."""

    pass
```

Usage:

```
def something(d: MutableObject[typing.Dict])
    d[1] = 'one'
```